# Force Vim's mksession to use relative paths?

Tags: session, vim, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm trying to save my session in Vim with relative paths to open files. With `cur_dir` in `sessionoptions`, the paths to files will be relative wrt. current directory, but the session file contains `cd /path/to/base/directory` command:

```
...
cd /path/to/base
badd +0 relpath1/file
badd +0 relpath2/file
...
```

If I leave `curdir` out of sessionoptions, the `cd` command disappears, but file paths will be absolute:

```
badd +0 /path/to/base/relpath1/file
badd +0 /path/to/base/relpath2/file
```

Is there a way to have *only* relative paths wrt. to whatever was the current directory when the session was created -- without plugins or writing scripts? So that the session file would only have:

```
badd +0 relpath1/file
badd +0 relpath2/file
```

My ultimate goal is to have a session file that I can copy around, e.g. from SVN checkout to another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that without setting up a wrapper function for it, AFAIK.

E.g. something like:

```
function! MakeSession()
  let b:sessiondir = getcwd()
  let b:filename = b:sessiondir . '/session.vim'
  exe "mksession! " . b:filename
  exe "edit! " . b:filename
  exe "g:^cd :d"
  exe "x" 
endfunction
```

Comment: Can you explain `g:^cd :d` a bit? I'm still having issue to make it work. I found this line is critical but have no clue what it does. Thx.

Comment: Hi @JohnChain, sure. It is an `ex` mode command that executes line deletion (`d`) globally on every line that matches the regex of `cd ` at the start of line.

Comment: This function doesn't save multi tabs AND it also closes one split from the active tab, in case of multiple vsplits.

Answer (score -1):

I modified Botykai's answer with an extra line to remove the absolute path globally.

```
function! MakeSession()
  let b:sessiondir = getcwd()
  let b:filename = b:sessiondir . '/_vimsession'
  exe "mksession! " . b:filename
  exe "edit! " . b:filename
  " Delete the line start with 'cd ...'
  exe "g:^cd :d"
  " Vim complains about b:sessiondir being undefined. So I use getcwd() directly
  " exe "%s:" . b:sessiondir . "::g". Use ':' to avoid path escape
  exe "%s:" . getcwd() . "/::g"
  " Save with 'x'
  exe "x"
endfunction
```

If someone can improve the function above to narrow down the lines to those only starting with `badd`, this will be better.

Comment: This functions doesn't save multi tabs.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem and I solve it with the function below inspired by [Zsolt Botykai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13323266/9249152)’s solution and [John Chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54874549/9249152)’s solution.
Plus, I defined a macro to execute this function with fewer keystroke.

```
function! MakeSession() 
    let cwd = getcwd()
    let filename = cwd . '/.vim'
    exe "mksession! " . filename
    exe "tabedit! " . filename
    exe "silent g:^cd :d"
    exe "silent g:^lcd :d"
    "exe "silent %s:\V" . cwd . "/::ge"
    " ^ Don’t work because getcwd() expand the ~ while mksession does not !
    exe "silent %s?\\v \\~=/.+/? ?g"
    " ^ backslash need to be protected
    exe "x"
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>mks :call MakeSession()<cr>
```

The main difference is the regex to remove full path.
It is needed because `getcwd` expands the `~` of home directory, but `mksession` does not (on Mac OS).

Comment: This functions doesn't save multi tabs.

Comment: Yes it does, I just re-checked! (Vim 8.2 and `sessionoptions = blank,buffers,curdir,folds,tabpages,winsize`)

Answer (score -1):

The solution is simpler when using `curdir` instead of `sesdir` (see `:help sessionoptions`) because the absolute path occurs only one time in session file (`cd path`). Hence, the `MakeSession` function is smaller (I called the session file `.vim`) :

```
function! MakeSession()
    exe "mksession! .vim"
    exe "tabedit! .vim"
    exe "silent g:^cd :d"
    exe "x"
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>mks :call MakeSession()<cr>
```

To choose the name of the session file (execution: `:call MakeNamedSession('foo')`) :

```
function! MakeNamedSession(arg)
    let radical = a:arg
    exe "mksession! " . radical . ".vim"
    exe "tabedit! " . radical . ".vim"
    exe "silent g:^cd :d"
    exe "x"
endfunction
```

Comment: This functions doesn't save multi tabs.

Comment: Yes it does, I used it on a daily basis (and I just re-checked)! (Vim 8.2 and `sessionoptions = blank,buffers,curdir,folds,tabpages,winsize`)